# Trying to plot a pdf table using camelot-py, but no table comes up

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-camelot

I am trying to plot the table to debug and find table coordinates, however the plot never appears on the screen. Camelot has built in functions that use the matplotlib library to plot the tables. I have all the dependencies downloaded for camelot, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the figure to appear.

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('example.pdf', flavor = 'lattice')

print(tables[0].parsing_report)

plt = camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='grid')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to add the Tkinter .mainloop() function after the .show() function to keep the figure up until I close it. without it, the figure closes immediately so that the code can run all the way through.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I seem to get 2 tkinter windows instead of just showing the Camelot one.

Answer (score 1):

copying from installed cli.py
i solved like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import camelot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # this to add


tables = camelot.read_pdf('example.pdf', flavor = 'lattice')

print(tables[0].parsing_report)

# was
# plt = camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='grid')

# new
camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='grid')

plt.show()
```